# Load Image from NAS with SharpCifs and Decode not work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, nas

I'd like to use a APP with a VPN-Connection to load images from a 
NAS Server by Using SharpCifs.

I get a Stream but on Bitmap.Factory.DecodeStream the Result Bitmap is null

Why can i get the Picture from the MemoryStream correct??

Using SharpCifs.Smb;

```
namespace AppSons
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

    ImageView networkImage;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
 // more Code
        networkImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewNetwork);


        Bitmap bmpa = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(GetImageBitmapFromPath("smb://192.168.1.10//Media/b.bmp"));
        networkImage.SetImageBitmap(bmpa);

    }


    private MemoryStream GetImageBitmapFromPath(string path)
    {
        var auth1 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("admin:admin");
        var imageFile = new SmbFile(path, auth1);


        var memStream = new MemoryStream();

        if (imageFile.Exists())
        {
            var readStream = imageFile.GetInputStream();
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];

            int size;
            while ((size = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                memStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
            readStream.Dispose();


            return memStream;
        }
        else
        {
            return memStream;
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
using SharpCifs.Smb;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        networkImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewNetwork);

        GetImageBitmapFromPath("smb://192.168.1.100/Media/Media/test.bmp");
    }

    private async void GetImageBitmapFromPath(string path)
    {
        byte[] imst = await LoadPic(path);
        Bitmap bmpa = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imst, 0, imst.Length);
        networkImage.SetImageBitmap(bmpa);            
    }

    private async Task<byte[]> LoadPic(string path)
    {
        var auth1 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("admin:admin");
        var imageFile = new SmbFile(path, auth1);

        var memStream = new MemoryStream();

        if (imageFile.Exists())
        {
            var readStream = imageFile.GetInputStream();
            ((Stream)readStream).CopyTo(memStream);

            return memStream.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```